# How could I write aggregation without exceeds maximum document size?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I got `exceeds maximum document size problem` exception by the query as follows,

```
pipe = [
    {"$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)} }}
    ]
res =db.patients.aggregate(pipe,allowDiskUse=True)
```

I fixed it by adding the `$project` operator,

However what if the document still over `16MB` even I use `$project` ?

What can I do ? any idea ? Thank you

```
pipe = [
    {"$project": {"birthday":1, "id":1}
    },
    {"$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)} }
     }
    ]
res =db.patients.aggregate(pipe,allowDiskUse=True)
```

## Exception

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', 'patients'), ('pipeline', [{'$match': {'birthday': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}}]), ('allowDiskUse', True)]) on namespace tw_insurance_security_development.$cmd failed: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default the result of aggregations are returned to you in a single BSON document, which is where the size restriction comes from. If you need to return more than that you can either:

- have the results be output to a collection. You do this by finishing your pipeline with

  {"$out": "some-collection-name"}

  You then query that collection as normal (you'll need to delete it yourself when you're done with it)
- have the results returned as a cursor, by specifying `useCursor=True` when you call aggregate.

Both of these options require mongodb 2.6: if you are still running mongodb 2.4 then this is just a fundamental limit of aggregations.

Comment: Would you be so kind and give a small Java example or at least a source? Best

Comment: Sorry - I'm not familiar with the Java mongo API

Comment: Thanks for the fast response anyway. I found a solution (with spring data and mongoDB):
`List<DBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
DBObject someMatchCriteria = new BasicDBObject();
someMatchCriteria.put("param", "value");
DBObject out = new BasicDBObject();
out.put("$out", "outCollectionName");
pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$match", someMatchCriteria));
pipeline.add(out);
mongoOperations.getCollection("inCollectionName").aggregate(pipeline);`

Answer (score 4):

As @Frederick said requires mongo 2.6 at least, For further reference, [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_4_and_2_6.html#aggregation-cursors) is the link from mongo documentation, which works similar to runCommand way but with db.collection.aggreagate, note that for document limit use "cursor" option, for sort limit use "allowDiskUse" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregateCursor(collection_name, $pipeLine, ["useCursor" => true])`.

```
pipe = [
    {"$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)} }}
    ]
res =db.patients.aggregateCursor(collection_name, pipe, ["useCursor" => true]);
        
$ret = [];

foreach ($taskList as $task){
  array_push($ret, $task);
}
        
return $ret;
```

Answer (score -5):

Use following snippet

```
db.patients.runCommand('aggregate', 
        {pipeline: [
    {"$project": {"birthday":1, "id":1}},
    {"$match": { "birthday":{"$gte":datetime.datetime(1987, 1, 1, 0, 0)} }}
], 
        allowDiskUse: true})
```

here  allowDiskUse will help to find out exceed 16 MB data

Comment: actually I've already enable the `allowDiskUse` option, but it still doesn't work