# MongoDB Aggregation Cursor with NodeJS Driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB v3.2 and I'm using the native nodejs driver v2.1. When running the aggregation pipeline on large data sets(1mil+ documents), I am encountering the following error:

```
 'aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)'
```

Here is my aggregation pipeline code:

```
var eventCollection = myMongoConnection.db.collection('events');
var cursor = eventCollection.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        event_type_id: {$eq: 89012}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$user_id",
                        score: {$sum: "$points"}
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        score: -1
                    }
                }
            ],
            {
                cursor: {
                    batchSize: 500
                },
                allowDiskUse: true,
                explain: false
            }, function () {

            });
```

Things I've tried:

```
//Using cursor event listeners. None of the on listeners seem to work. Always get error about 16mb.
cursor.on("data", function (data) {
   console.log("Some data: ", data);
});
cursor.on("end", function (data) {
   console.log("End of data: ", data);
});

//Using forEach. Which I thought would allow for >16mb because it's used in conjunction with the batchSize and cursor.
cursor.forEach(function (item) {

})
```

I've seen in other answers ([How could I write aggregation without exceeds maximum document size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644587/how-could-i-write-aggregation-without-exceeds-maximum-document-size)) that I need to have the results returned by a cursor, so how do I properly do that? I just can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions on what the batchSize should be?

I am using the native mongodb package - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native for a nodejs project not the mongo command line.

Comment: The `.forEach()` has no place here since an "aggregation cursor" is actually just a [node "stream"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interface, and therefore only the "data" event is actually doing anything. However if that is how your code is actually set up then this would suggest that you have a MongoDB 2.4 or lower server instance, which of course does not support a "cursor/stream" response. I would therefore suggest you upgrade right away, since that would be a "very old" release now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644587/how-could-i-write-aggregation-without-exceeds-maximum-document-size

Comment: I have verified my MongoDB instance is version 3.2.1

Comment: I don't believe you. The server is clearly not a capable version or you are not in fact using the node native driver that you claim to be using, or your actual code has different syntax usage to what is here. This simply does not reproduce and the error indicates that any cursor options are being ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It was not working because I was passing in a callback function as the last parameter in the aggregate method. By passing null, it allowed the stream to work as expected. Changes shown below:

```
var cursor = eventCollection.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    event_type_id: {$eq: 89012}
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$user_id",
                    score: {$sum: "$points"}
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    score: -1
                }
            }
        ],
        {
            cursor: {
                batchSize: 500
            },
            allowDiskUse: true,
            explain: false
        }, null);
```