# node js query the collection from $out

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I am using mongoDB and nodejs for my application. I have document in db as

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a868d785e5436aeed0502c0"), 
"symbol" : "ABC",
"values" : [ 
    {
        "High" : 53.0,
        "Close" : 51.85,
        "Open" : 50.8
    }, 
    {
        "High" : 51.35,
        "Close" : 50.25,
        "Open" : 50.35
    }
  ]
}
```

To calculate the percentage change between values[0].Close and values[1].Close, I am using the below code.If shootup >= 5 return **true** else **false**.

```
var History = require('../DBmodel/sHistory');
History.aggregate([{
                "$addFields": {
                    "shootup": {
                        "$gte": [{
                            "$multiply": [{
                                    "$cond": [{
                                            "$eq": [{
                                                "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1]
                                            }, 0]
                                        },
                                        1, {
                                            "$divide": [{
                                                "$subtract": [{
                                                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 0]
                                                }, {
                                                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1]
                                                }]
                                            }, {
                                                "$arrayElemAt": ["$values.Close", 1]
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                100
                            ]
                        }, 5]
                    }
                }
            }], function(err, themeList) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                res.json(themeList);
            });
```

on execution I am getting error as - aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

so I used $out to create another collection. But I am not sure how to query the new collection in nodejs as we have not declared variable for new collection model.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Clearly the error is telling you that `next()` is not defined. That is the problem, and has nothing to do with MongoDB. Is the second code block inside an Express controller or something like that?

Comment: Oops..Sorry, I should check that as I assumed it will be there but missed in this method. Thanks for reply. Now I am getting the next error as aggregate  is exceeding output > 16MB. so how should I send the response? If using $out to create new collection then how to Query ?

Comment: That's a completely different question. Either edit this question to reflect that or ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks ...and I have edited the question

Comment: You should remove the old error that has nothing to do with the current error you're getting. As it is this question is really confusing.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588164/mongodb-aggregation-cursor-with-nodejs-driver?noredirect=1&lq=1)?