# How to fix ‘exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)’ error in MongoDB PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I'm trying to perform an aggregate on mongodb and throw me this error!

exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB).

I am using the following specifics:

PHP Version 5.4.7

Driver MongoDB PHP Version 1.3.2RC1

MongoDB version 2.6.12

> version => 2.6.12, targetMinOS => Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2,javascriptEngine => V8, bits => 64, maxBsonObjectSize => 16777216

My collection is to +200k documents.

> Yii::app()->bd->$collection->aggregate($pipeline);

I have tried with:

> `$consulta =Yii::app()->bd->command(array('aggregate' => $collection,'pipeline' => $pipeline,'allowDiskUse' => true,'cursor'=> array('batchSize' =>10)))`

and only returns a first batch with the first (firstBatch)10 documents:

> [id] => 4272376035505,[ns] => collection, [firstBatch]=>data

Does not return secondBatch... xxxBatch

I have tried to do the second batch (secondBatch ... xxxBatch)  (https://derickrethans.nl/cursors-in-mongodb.html) with:

> $consulta->getNext();

and return:

**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getNext() on a non-object in.

also try to use $out:

> {"$ out": "nombre-alguna colección"}

And I created the collection but it does not fill me with the documents, apart they are dynamic collections and it does not help me to be creating an auxiliary collection for each collection dynamic.

I do not want to have to count the documents and then do a limit with a skip, to 500 in 500

> I would like to be able to bring all the lots with the "batchSize" or all the data at once

Comment: probarly duplicated [How could I write aggregation without exceeds maximum document size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644587/how-could-i-write-aggregation-without-exceeds-maximum-document-size)

Comment: also try to use $ out and I created the collection but it does not fill me with the documents, apart they are dynamic collections and it does not help me to be creating an auxiliary collection for each collection dynamic.