# how to do two groupBy query in single aggregation based on the lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections and I need to group documents from both using a single query using `$lookup` and `$group`.
Here is my db data and the expected output:

**currentBills table**

```
const currentBills = [
  {
    memberId: 1,
    name: 'Mark',
    status: 'paid'
  },
  {
    memberId: 2,
    name: 'Steve',
    status: 'unpaid'
  },
  {
    memberId: 3,
    name: 'William',
    status: 'paid'
  }
];
```

**pastBills table**

```
const pastBills = [
  {
    memberId: 5,
    name: 'Joe',
    status: 'paid'
  },
  {
    memberId: 8,
    name: 'Carlos',
    status: 'paid'
  },
  {
    memberId: 25,
    name: 'ben',
    status: 'unpaid'
  }
];
```

**expected output**

```
const result = {
  CurrentBill: {
    paid: [
      {
        memberId: 1,
        name: 'Mark',
        status: 'paid'
      },

      {
        memberId: 3,
        name: 'William',
        status: 'paid'
      }
    ],
    unpaid: [
      {
        memberId: 2,
        name: 'Steve',
        status: 'unpaid'
      }
    ]
  },
  pastBill: {
    paid: [
      {
        memberId: 5,
        name: 'Joe',
        status: 'paid'
      },
      {
        memberId: 8,
        name: 'Carlos',
        status: 'paid'
      }
    ],
    unpaid: [
      {
        memberId: 25,
        name: 'ben',
        status: 'unpaid'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**my query**

```
db.getCollection('currentBills').aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "pastBills",
       localField: "memberId",
       foreignField: "memberId",
       as: "bill"
     }
},{
    $unwind : "$bill"
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : "$status"
            }
        }
        ])
```

How to group each collections by the `status` and return a single result? Is this possible using a single aggregation query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this possible using a single aggregation query?*

Its possible in single query but really bad idea, it may cause the performance issues, it would be better if you do 2 separate queries first for `currentBills` and second for `pastBills` and merge both the result in your programming language, because both the collections are different. see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sj4sWGlZZuF) solution for single collection.

For single query you can try,

- `$addFields` to add `coll` field to identify this is `currentBills` document
- `$unionWith` to union `pastBills` documents and also `$addFields` to add `coll` field  to identify `pastBills` document
- `$group` by `coll` and `status` and construct the root `members` array
- `$group` by only `coll` and construct the array of `coll` in key-value format
- `$group` by null and construct the root document array in key-value format after converting coll from array to object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace documents in root after converting it from array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.currentBills.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { coll: "currentBills" } },
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "pastBills",
      pipeline: [{ $addFields: { coll: "pastBills" } }]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { coll: "$coll", status: "$status" },
      members: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.coll",
      coll: { $push: { k: "$_id.status", v: "$members" } }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: { $arrayToObject: "$coll" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$root" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x7XyOAwJocu)

---

> **READ THIS BEFORE USE THIS QUERY:**
>
> - **[MongoDB Limits and Thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limits-and-thresholds)** The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
> - See question [How could I write aggregation without exceeds maximum document size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644587/how-could-i-write-aggregation-without-exceeds-maximum-document-size)

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/qyA1QsjfAsT

Note - This is overkill if you don't have limited set of records

```
db.currentBills.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { // group by status
      _id: "$status",
      currentBills: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: { // add pastBills to for the status paid in paid doc and unpaid in unpaid doc
      from: "pastBills",
      let: { status: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$status", "$status" ] } } }
      ],
      as: "pastBills"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { // reshape docs with paid and unpaid keys
      currentBills: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [ "$_id", "paid" ] }, // condition
          { paid: "$currentBills" }, // true
          { unpaid: "$currentBills" } // false
        ]
      },
      pastBills: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [ "$_id", "paid" ] },
          { paid: "$currentBills" },
          { unpaid: "$currentBills" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null, // group all documents
      currentBills: { $push: "$currentBills" },
      pastBills: { $push: "$pastBills" }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])
```